# Photon loss errors versus photon subtraction errors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-information, quantum-optics, quantum-error-correction

Cat codes, $|0_L\rangle\approx|\alpha\rangle + |-\alpha\rangle $ and $|1_L\rangle\approx|i\alpha\rangle + |-i\alpha\rangle$, are said correct single-photon *loss* errors in the literature. Similarly, binomial codes are said to correct for some finite number of photon *loss* errors.

See for example: [Bergmann, M., & van Loock, P. (2016). Quantum error correction against photon loss using multicomponent cat states. Physical Review A, 94(4), 042332.](https://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.94.042332)

Is it more appropriate to say they correct photon *subtraction* or *annihilation* errors instead?

Any small photon loss on a cat quickly destroys any coherence whereas, photon *subtraction* turns a cat into a complementary with the same amplitude. Clearly, these are two very different processes.

Do the popular GKP codes designed to correct displacement errors, correct for photon *loss* or *subtraction* as described above?

Comment: Can you please provide a reference to the literature referring to "loss"?

Comment: Added a reference in the question

Comment: The reference provided explicitly talks about amplitude damping, so the question is probably answered therein. Section II starts with "It is rather well known that there is a twofold effect when a cat state, i.e., a superposition of two distinct coherent
states such as $\propto |\alpha\rangle+|-\alpha\rangle$ is subject to a full photon-loss (amplitude-damping) channel" and then goes on to explain how $\alpha\to\eta\alpha$ while a phase flip also occurs

Comment: Thank you @QuantumMechanic From what I understood amplitude damping/full-photon loss channel is composed of different amounts of photon loss errors (which I was referring to as subtraction errors). Loss (subtraction) errors with a particular value of photon number do not occur naturally as we typically have amplitude damping/full-photon loss channels as the noise model in general physical settings. In that case, would it be fair to say cat codes can *not* correct full-photon loss errors?

Comment: What would be an example of a practical situation where the noise model is given by a specific number (or up to some specific number) of photon losses?

Comment: I am confused about whether single-photon loss errors can be corrected in a full-photon loss channel. The reference talks about it in Appendix B on KL conditions I think but I don't have the intuition for why this error correction works

Comment: @SaurabhShringarpure I'm not quite sure what you mean. Amnplitude damping or full photon loss or the most general type of loss is a transformation $a\to\eta a$, which can be enacted by some of the light coupling to another mode by a beam splitter and then neglecting the other mode. This is a very general description, and for coherent states it happens to enact the transformation $|\alpha\rangle\to|\eta\alpha\rangle$, which is exactly the same as classical amplitude damping

Comment: This is a continuous description of the amount of loss, not talking about losing exactly some integer $k$ photons

Comment: Whereas: acting on a state with an annihilation operator consitutes photon subtraction, and would change the parity of these states

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146206/discussion-between-saurabh-shringarpure-and-quantum-mechanic).